# My Wordpress activation hook isn't working

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, activation

I just can't see why my activation hook isn't working.

```
/* ****Debug function ****/
function console_log( $data ){

  echo '<script>';
  echo 'console.log('. json_encode( $data ) .')';
  echo '</script>';
}
console_log ("Hello from main");

/* ***Set up activation and deactivation functions**
*** Activate sets up the WP tables "picm"**
*** Deactivate removes the WP tables "picm" */
function picm_activate() {
    global $wpdb;
    console_log ("Hello from activate");
    $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE ".$wpdb->prefix."picm_menus (
        m_id integer INT, 
        m_type INT, 
        m_stype VARCHAR(50), 
        m_sizeh VARCHAR(20), 
        msizev VARCHAR(20), 
        m_elements INT, 
        m_double TINYINT)"); // to be completed
    $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE ".$wpdb->prefix."picm_elements (
        m_elid INT, 
        m_id integer INT, 
        m_el_source VARCHAR (500))"); // to be completed
    }
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'picm_activate' );
```

The console output is:

```
GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-admin/plugins.php?action=activate&plugin=picture-menus%2Fpicture-menus.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_wpnonce=cbb8f69901
[HTTP/2.0 302 Found 236ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-admin/plugins.php?error=true&charsout=98&plugin=picture-menus%2Fpicture-menus.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_error_nonce=46dd486539
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 284ms]

Hello from main plugins.php:1:9
GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=dashicons,admin-bar,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menus,wp-pointer,widgets&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=,site-icon,l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check&ver=5.3
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=5.3
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.3
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-content/plugins/picture-menus/images/pic_menus_admin_icon.png
[HTTP/2.0 404 Not Found 250ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,underscore,wp-util&ver=5.3
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/wp-polyfill.min.js?ver=7.4.4
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-includes/js/dist/dom-ready.min.js?ver=2.5.1
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-includes/js/dist/a11y.min.js?ver=2.5.1
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-includes/js/wp-sanitize.min.js?ver=5.3
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-admin/js/updates.min.js?ver=5.3
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/core.min.js?ver=1.11.4
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.js?ver=3.1-20121105
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-admin/js/plugin-install.min.js?ver=5.3
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-admin/js/svg-painter.js?ver=5.3
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-includes/js/dist/hooks.min.js?ver=2.6.0
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-includes/js/heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.3
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-includes/js/wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.3
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 load-scripts.php:8:552
GEThttps://theberne.com/vanilla/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.3
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/30a62903f49afdd0623c276d372fa37b?s=26&d=mm&r=g
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/30a62903f49afdd0623c276d372fa37b?s=64&d=mm&r=g
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]

GEThttps://theberne.com/favicon.ico
[HTTP/2.0 200 OK 0ms]
```

​As you can see, the console output from the main (Hello from main) is present, but the output from within the hooked activation function doesn't show.  The tables don't get created either.

Comment: Just wondering, have you run this without any of the console_log() output? (Assuming you have, but have to ask.) Generally, when a plugin is activated, direct output like that will throw an error (and your console looks like an error is present).  Try using the "Debug Bar" plugin along with the "Debug Bar Plugin Activation" plugin.  That should give you some error output (if any are present) so you can see more directly what they are.

Comment: I have removed all reference to console_log() including the function itself and installed "Debug Bar" - can't find "Debug Bar Plugin Activation".  I now get a message "The plugin generated 918 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “ headers already sent ” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin."  I can't see any syntax errors in my code and my editor (jedit) seems to think it is fine.

Comment: The "unexpected output" is the error message that you need in order to debug the issue. Without knowing what it says, everything is a guess. [Here's the link to the Debug Bar Plugin Activation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-plugin-activation/). That will give you the ability to find out what's in that error message.

Comment: Oh - How daft!.  My SQL was wrong.  Silly mistake.  Thanks for your help "butlerblog".  How do I close this question to avoid wasting anyone else's time?